# How i foreach loop in listitems values entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 lists. One has 3 records like 1 , 2 , 3 and seconds list holds table records. All i wanna do add first list values to second list.

I hope [image: this picture] helps.

```
foreach (var itemAgent in listofValues)
{
    foreach (var item in formSorgu)
    {
        #region MyRegion
        CrmDonusleri crmEkleme = new CrmDonusleri()
        {
            AradigiBolge = item.bolge,
            AramaTarihi = Convert.ToDateTime(item.aratarihi),
            Musno = item.musno,
            GeriDonusYapildiMi = false,
            AtanmaTarihi = DateTime.Now,
            KanalAdi = item.kanal,
            ProgramAdi = item.program,
            AtananAgent = itemAgent
        };
        DbContext.CrmDonusleri.Add(crmEkleme);
        #endregion
    }
}
DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

`listofValues` hold 3 records and `formSorgu` hold 2000 records. `listofValues` as List One and `formSorgu` as `List Two`. And i want my final list like Picture below.

I don't think my code is right. Please show me the right way to write this query.

```
for (int i = formSorgu.Count + 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    foreach (var itemAgent in listofValues)
    {
        CrmDonusleri crmEkkle = new CrmDonusleri()
        {
            Musno = formSorgu.FirstOrDefault().musno,
            AtananAgent = itemAgent
        };
    }
}
```

when i use this code it gets one record from `formSorgu` but add to `listofValues` 3 times i just want it to foreach one time and go out from `foreach` loop and carry on other for loop record.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried.  Right now it's not completely clear what you are asking.

Comment: i added new Picture.

Comment: still not clear? juharr???

Comment: and you edit my question but still on hold.

Comment: So you just want to add the values of one list to another wrapping back around to the beginning of that list once you reach the end?  If so, then just keep track of the first lists index like this `int i = 0; foreach(var item in ListToUpdate) { item.Whatever = FromList[i].Whatever; i++; if(i >= FromList.Count) i = 0; }`

Comment: BTW I did not update your question, but the update was deserved to fix the formatting of your code and remove your belligerent comments.

Comment: there must be a button to gave a bad answer to Show you how you feel people. do you think your question helps? there is no relation with my question.   "Can you show what you've tried. Right now it's not completely clear whats your answer" ????

Comment: I write a SQL to generate the list 3:        SELECT a.ID,a.Value,b.Value FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS rn, * FROM t2
        ) AS a INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS rn,COUNT(0)OVER() AS t1Count, * FROM t1
        ) AS b ON a.rn%t1Count=b.rn%t1Count
        ORDER BY a.ID

Comment: so thanks to stackoverflow mods for not understanding my question and down vote for my question. 

thank you nolan shang i dont like to use sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

actually, i love to share i am not like stackover mods. so i found an excellent answer on internet. you can find a link that equally selecting items from list and psuedo run.

[solution link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/691177/Evenly-selecting-items-from-a-list-in-a-pseudo-ran)

that is a link i used. and i turn my code like this;

```
     var randoAgent = new RandomPicker<string>(listofValues);
            foreach (var itemSorgu in formSorgu)
            {
                var item = randoAgent.PickItem();
                CrmDonusleri crmEkle = new CrmDonusleri()
                {
                    Musno = itemSorgu.musno,
                    TelNo = itemSorgu.telno,
                    AtananAgent = item,
                    AradigiBolge = itemSorgu.bolge,
                    AramaTarihi = Convert.ToDateTime(itemSorgu.aratarihi),
                    AtanmaTarihi = DateTime.Now,
                    Ekleyen = itemSorgu.ekleyen,
                    GeriDonusYapildiMi = false,
                    KanalAdi = itemSorgu.kanal,
                    ProgramAdi = itemSorgu.program
                };
                DbContext.CrmDonusleri.Add(crmEkle);
            }
            DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

and works perfect.